# Chrome reopens previous tabs even after shutdown

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7, chrome-for-android

On my Nexus 7 when starting Chrome it reopens the previous tabs.  I can understand doing this as I switch from Chrome to another running app and then back to Chrome, but not if I've shut the app down, and certainly not if I've rebooted the device. Yet for some reason Chrome assumes that I must want to look again at the last thing I was looking at. Rather presumptuous.

I would have thought there would be an option to turn that "feature" on or off, but I've not been able to find it.

Is it possible to disable the opening of previously viewed tabs?

Comment: I think this is probably necessary to work with the recent tab-sync feature. If you want to open a tab you had open on your device on your desktop browser later, for instance. That said, that's the default behavior and I haven't seen a way to change it. Every once in a while I'll go in and close (almost) all my old tabs. Fortunately, once you've opened up the tab accordion it's easy to just tap-tap-tap to close them.

Comment: It's an intended feature and can't be turned off. Why do you don't want to restore your previous opened tabs? I couldn't live without this feature.

Comment: I guess what's really missing on Android's Chrome is a `Close all tabs` and/or `Close tabs to the right` feature.

Answer (score 3):

I too want my Chrome browser to open without the previous tabs. There should be an option to turn this feature off, or a prompt on startup asking whether to open previous tabs as it does on the desktop. When I'm done with browsing, I just swipe the browser off. I don't want to have to close each tab separately before exiting to stop those tabs from reopening when I open the browser again.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the expected behavior while launching the Chrome browser with the`Sign in` feature enabled.

Here's how to [sign out](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2392075) from within the Chrome browser:

1. Touch `Menu` > `Settings` > `your email address` > `Disconnect Google Account`.
2. In the confirmation dialog that appears, touch `Disconnect`.

Note that if you had your device configured to synchronize in the background at regular intervals, it is still configurued to sync and update your emails with your google account. This procedure just prevents the Chrome browser from loading a previous session state at browser launch because the *browser* is signed in.

Comment: Sounds credible, however disconnecting my browser from my account did nothing for the behaviour of re-opening the previously open tab.

Comment: Not sure what you should do. Maybe clear the browser cache/cookies? Also, maybe you have some Chrome addon `extension` that includes being a session state manager among whatever else you might be using it for.

Answer (score 1):

Leandros is right that it is an intended feature, and there is no way to turn off. There is a report on the Chromium project to allow close all tabs on tablets: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=268157

I urge everyone interested to voice their opinions on the bug thread.